# Dropdown Menu Table Call Requires Extra Click After Selection with JQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a list of dropdown items, that when selected should bring up a table connected to the value. When using this jquery code to call the table, I select the first dropdown, then select the second dropdown (which is used for the value of the table id). However, once I select the second dropdown, the table does not coming up. In order for the table to show up, I have to click the second dropdown again, then click off, and then it will show. Any suggestions for what I'm doing wrong here?

Here are selection options

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('select[name!="dropdownmain"]').hide();
    $('select[name="' + $('select[name="dropdownmain"]').val() + '"]').show();
    $('select[name="dropdownmain"]').change(function(){
        $('select[name!="dropdownmain"]').hide();
        $('select[name="' + $(this).val() + '"]').show();
    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid one-third">
    <select name="dropdownmain" id="" title="">
           <option value="">Select manufacturer</option>
        <option value="dropdownmain1">Cooler Master </option>
        <option value="dropdownmain2">Corsair </option>
        <option value="dropdownmain3">Logitech </option>
        <option value="dropdownmain4">Mad Catz  </option>
        <option value="dropdownmain5">Mionix   </option>
        <option value="dropdownmain6">Razer   </option>
        <option value="dropdownmain7">Roccat    </option>
        <option value="dropdownmain8">SteelSeries    </option>
    </select>
    <select name="dropdownmain1" id="" title="" class="dropdown1">
        <option value="">Choose you mouse</option>
    <option value="14">Cooler Master Alcor</option>
    <option value="15">Cooler Master Havoc</option>
    <option value="16">Cooler Master Inferno</option>
    <option value="19">Cooler Master Mizar</option>
    <option value="20">Cooler Master Reaper</option>
    <option value="21">Cooler Master Recon</option>
    <option value="22">Cooler Master Sentinel Advance II</option>
    <option value="26">Cooler Master Sentinel Advance</option>
    <option value="17">Cooler Master Sentinel III</option>
    <option value="23">Cooler Master Sentinel Z3RO-G</option>
    <option value="24">Cooler Master Spawn</option>
    <option value="25">Cooler Master Xornet</option>
    <option value="18">Cooler Master Xornet II</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I think your example is incomplete because I don't see any table at all

Comment: @Sagnalrac - sorry about that, I didn't include the table. Would you mind checking out the table in action at https://whatmouse.com/mouse-comparison/ thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can do it without jQuery DataTable, you can do it with a regular table.

Take a look at my example:

```js
$(document).ready(function($){
    
    $("#ddManufacturer").change(function() {
             $('select[name!="dropdownmain"]').hide();
        $('select[name="' + $(this).val() + '"]').show();
    });
    
    /*$('select[name!="dropdownmain"]').hide();
    $('select[name="' + $('select[name="dropdownmain"]').val() + '"]').show();
    $('select[name="dropdownmain"]').change(function(){
        $('select[name!="dropdownmain"]').hide();
        $('select[name="' + $(this).val() + '"]').show();
    });*/
    $("#dropdownmain1").change(function() {
            loadTable($(this).val());
    });
});

function loadTable(productId) {

        $("#result").show();
    
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/SagnalracSO/repo/products",
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { id: productId },
        //dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                        var product = data[0];
                        
            $("#tblProdInfo").empty();
            var html = '<thead><tr>' +
                                    '<th>' + product.name + '</th>' +
                                    '<th><img src="http://whatmouse.com/wp-content/uploads/' + product.image + '" height="60px;" width="60px;" /></th></tr></thead>' +
                        '<tbody><tr>' +
                                    '<td>Launch Year</td><td>' + product.launch_year + '</td></tr>' + 
                        '<tr><td>Dimensions, mm</td><td>' + product.dimensions + '</td></tr>' +
                        '<tr><td>Weight, gramms</td><td>' + product.weight + '</td></tr></tbody>';
                        
            $("#tblProdInfo").append(html);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error('There was something wrong! Error Type: ' + textStatus + '. Description: ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.one-third {
    width: 31.2%;
}

.grid {
    margin-right: 3.2%;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

.one-third select {
    margin: 5px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#result {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.tablepress {
    margin-top: -10px;
    border: 1px solid #2fa5cd;
}

.tablepress {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.tablepress thead th, .tablepress tfoot th {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #2fa5cd;
}

.tablepress thead th {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tablepress tbody td, .tablepress tfoot th {
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.tablepress td, .tablepress th {
    padding: 8px;
    border: none;
    background: 0 0;
    text-align: left;
    float: none !important;
}

.tablepress tbody td {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #414141;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid one-third">
    <select id="ddManufacturer" name="dropdownmain">
        <option value="">Select manufacturer</option>
        <option value="dropdownmain1">Cooler Master </option>
        <option value="dropdownmain2">Corsair </option>
        <option value="dropdownmain3">Logitech </option>
        <option value="dropdownmain4">Mad Catz  </option>
        <option value="dropdownmain5">Mionix   </option>
        <option value="dropdownmain6">Razer   </option>
        <option value="dropdownmain7">Roccat    </option>
        <option value="dropdownmain8">SteelSeries    </option>
    </select>
    <select id="dropdownmain1" name="dropdownmain1" class="dropdown1" style="display: none;" >
        <option value="">Choose you mouse</option>
        <option value="14">Cooler Master Alcor</option>
        <option value="15">Cooler Master Havoc</option>
        <option value="16">Cooler Master Inferno</option>
    </select>
    <div id="result" style="display: none;">
      <table id="tblProdInfo" class="tablepress">
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Important:** You'll need to replace in the Ajax **url** property, my server for yours (the server where you're gonna get the data), and notice that I used the original urls (from the website that you shared with me) for the images. You'll need to replace those urls with the urls from your server (where you store them)